# Conditional sentence type 1

Tags: conditional-constructions, backshifting

> I have passed the final exam at university. 
> My father has already promised to pay me a holiday to London if I *pass/passed*.

Should we use "pass" or "passed" here?

Comment: Hello & welcome to the site. Please note that we are not a proofreading service - enter your own thoughts on the subjects and we will be happy to add ours.

Comment: Is the first sentence intended to establish a fact that we should use when we are making sense of the second sentence?

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> My father *has/had* already promised to pay me a holiday to London if I **pass**.

The timeframe of *pass* is when the father made the promise, so present tense is fine.

*Has* or *had* could be used depending on other context.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in conditional type 1 sentences, if-clause is in the simple present and the main clause is in the future, for example, my father will pay me a holiday to London if I pass my final exam at university.

I think the main clause "my father has already promised to pay........London" indicates the event to take place in the future.  So I think it's grammatically correct if you say "My father has already promised to pay me a holiday to London if I pass the final exam.